# Error JAVA0000 - Type androidx.collection.ArraySetKt is defined multiple times

Tags: xamarin.android, maui

When trying to rebuild app I am migrating from Xamarin.android to MAUI, I am getting the following error.

It is not actually in the solution path, it is in the c drive under nuget\packages.

I dont know if this is important, but I noticed in the error, one path ends in: net7.0-android33.0
The other path ends in: net6.0-android31.0

**Error JAVA0000**  Error in C:\Users\asbissada.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.2\buildTransitive\net7.0-android33.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class:
**Type androidx.collection.ArraySetKt is defined multiple times**: C:\Users\asbissada.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.2\buildTransitive\net7.0-android33.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class, C:\Users\asbissada.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx\1.2.0.10\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class
Compilation failed

I see other JAVA0000 on SO but haven't seen this one. This is what the AndroidX packages look like (I don't see ArraySetKt in there). Although I do notice Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common has a warning symbol even though its on the latest version:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding these nuget packages as Android dependencies:

`Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection`

`Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection.Ktx`

Comment: Thanks for this! You saved me a whole bunch of time.

Comment: Thank you, worked for me as well! Do you know why @Riccardo Minato or @
tonyedwardspz

Comment: @wallef Honestly, i didn't fully understand it. It has something to do with original Google libraries dependencies and their .NET bindings, which have to keep the same dependencies and if they're not completely up-to-date can cause some troubles.